# How to prove the following inequality with complete induction?

Tags: inequality, summation, induction, products

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and let $a_1, ... , a_n > 0.$

Show that:

[image: inequality]

I got the hint that we have to use this induction step for the induction proof:

[image: Hint]

And thats what I got so far in the Induction step but i only come to dead ends:

My first try:

[image: first try first page]

[image: first try second page]

And my second try:

[image: second try]

I hope you can help me or give me a hint and thank you in advance for the answers.

Comment: In the hint, $k$ is doing double duty in the notation. Can you clarify if the inner summation should be $ \sum_{k}^n a_k$ or $ \sum_{i=1}^n a_i$?